# How to typeguard the children of an Element in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two custom element classes:

```
class A extends ... { ... }
customElements.define("phi-a", A);
class B extends ... { ... }
customElements.define("phi-b", B);
```

And I put those custom elements into JSX.IntrinsicElements like this:

```
interface AAttrs extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {}
interface BAttrs extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {}

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            "phi-a": React.DetailedHTMLProps<AAttrs, HTMLElement>;
            "phi-b": React.DetailedHTMLProps<BAttrs, HTMLElement>;
        }
    }
}
```

So I don't get any error in using them in render like this:

```
export default function TestComponent() {
    return (
        <phi-a>
            <phi-b/>
        </phi-a>
    );
}
```

But I want to typeguard the children of `phi-a` to be only `phi-b`. So I tried this:

```
interface AAttrs extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    children: B;
}
```

But it occurs an error:

```
Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'B': <Here comes the fields of the class B>, and 349 more.ts(2740)
```

I also tried changing all occurrence of HTMLElement type in `AAttrs`, `BAttrs`, and `IntrinsicElements` to corresponding types, but it didn't work as I guessed.